# Custom print cost calculator for printing business

Tags: web-apps, ecommerce

First of all, I am not a web developer. I manage a small printing business. I manage our company's website and our company's social media profiles, as well as our Google Ads campaigns.

Our website was built using Google sites. I know it isn't the best website builder, but all we needed was a website with a couple of pages that showcase our work, so our customers can inform themselves about what we do and what services we offer. And it has actually been working better that you'd initially think. I have had quite a few customers compliment us on how nice our website was.

However, I'd like to expand to something completely different that most of the website building platforms in the market don't seem to offer; calculating the cost of e.g. printing a .pdf file online and then giving the customer to pay for that service.

Take for example: https://doxzoo.com/pdf-printing

You can upload your .pdf file, and their website calculates the cost based on the number of pages on that file, taking into account input from the user, things like whether it will be a full colour or B&W print, if they want it to be spiral bound, etc.

Is there any platform, like e.g Shopify or Woocommerce, or some extension for one of those platforms, that allow you to do something like that, even without all the features that I mentioned earlier? Anything that doesn't require extensive coding knowledge goes. I would really like to make this happen myself, so I can have full control over it throughout its lifespan. I am ok with paying a monthly subscription or a one time fee for e.g. a plugin.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen excel embeded on peoples website. We have created a workbook that calculates the cost of printing pictures based on size and how many as well for offline use by our sister company. The customer could choose a a drop down for black and white or color, and they would input how many pages are in the document.

If you don't want to hire us or anyone else and you do have excel knowledge you could make it in that.

[https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773#:~:text=%20Embed%20your%20Excel%20workbook%20on%20your%20web,and%20click%20a%20guest%20link.%20Select...%20More%20](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/embed-your-excel-workbook-on-your-web-page-or-blog-from-sharepoint-or-onedrive-for-business-7af74ce6-e8a0-48ac-ba3b-a1dd627b7773#:%7E:text=%20Embed%20your%20Excel%20workbook%20on%20your%20web,and%20click%20a%20guest%20link.%20Select...%20More%20)